# How to change useragent of default Ubuntu Web browser?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, webbrowser-app

If it possible, how to change/substitute of user-agent for default Ubuntu GNOME Web browser?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1-st way (GUI):

1. Installing **dconf Editor**:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dconf-editor -y
```

2. Run it:

```
$ dconf-editor
```

3. Go to:

```
/org/gnome/epiphany/web/user-agent
```

4. Switch **Use default value** to **OFF**
5. Insert Your custom user-agent string to **Custom value** field.

[image]

6. Close **dconf Editor**.
7. Chaeck Your user-agent with link: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent

### 2-nd way (Command-line):

1. To set use this command and replace **YOUR_CUSTOM_USER_AGENT** to your value:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Epiphany.web:/org/gnome/epiphany/web/ user-agent 'YOUR_CUSTOM_USER_AGENT'
```

For Example:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Epiphany.web:/org/gnome/epiphany/web/ user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'
```

2. To check current user-agent value use command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Epiphany.web:/org/gnome/epiphany/web/ user-agent
```

3. To revert to the default user-agent:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.Epiphany.web:/org/gnome/epiphany/web/ user-agent
```

### Result:

[image]